# Press [X] button to close JFrame won't invoke dispose method

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have set up a JFrame like this:

```
public class XFrame extends JFrame {

public XFrame() {
    setSize(100, 100);
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    System.out.println("Dispose get called");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            XFrame f = new XFrame();
            f.setTitle("Hello World");
            //f.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

What I expect is that when I press the close button [X] then the dispose method will be called. However, it's the situation only when DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE is set as the DefaultCloseOperation (???). Java really surprises me here. How to implement a method that would be called in both case of DefaultCloseOperation value (DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE & EXIT_ON_CLOSE)?

Comment: Looking at your code, I'd put `f.setTitle` and `f.setDefaultCloseOperation` into `XFrame`'s constructor.

Answer (score 5):

If you do `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` there's precious little need to dispose, as all resources are "disposed" anyway when the JVM exits. I'm putting "disposed" in quotes because in this automatic case, the `dispose` method is apparently not being called.

Be aware that the public methods in Swing are there for *you* to call, not all are necessarily called by the innards of Swing. For example, there are `setSize()` and `setLocation()` and `setBounds()` methods – do the former 2 call the latter, or the other way around? It's not defined, so you shouldn't assume.

Similarly, if you want to do something when the frame closes, the way to ensure it would be to hook a `WindowListener` to the frame, and put your closing action in `windowClosing()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a WindowListener with the windowClosing() method implemented? That should tell you when it's either a dispose or an exit.

Edit: Just tried it out - should do the job, depending on whether or not you *must* do something in dispose() rather than in windowClosing().

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `dispose` does not mention that it get called when the system gets down. I think it's still not assured (by the javadoc) that it is called for `DISPOSE_ON_EXIT`...
Anyway `System.exit`, used by `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, is kind of *brutal*, it shutdowns the virtual machine and there is hardly any chance to run any method after that (despite some finalization hoocks and methods).

*I personaly don't like to use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` because of that and because it's function can be inhibited by using an SecurityManager*

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you put instead of EXIT_ON_CLOSE  JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE?